# Jasper Reports with iReport multiple records not showing up

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Hi I am creating an invoice report using iReport. I have a table named orderstable and within it there are 6 fields; Order Number, Account Number, Invoice Number, Description, Amount and VAT.

Data contained is as follows:

```
record 1: 1, PA0001, 10005, Monthly Charge, 200, 20
record 2: 2, PA0001, 10005, Training Delivered, 250, 20
```

Now when I run my report it asks me for the invoice number. In this case I put in 10005 and this returns a report with the 1st record only. How can I get it so that the details of the Description, Amount and VAT fields are returned for both records?

Thank you.

Comment: Did u add outher fields to jasper report?

Comment: Yes I have added them. There is a table with the headings description, amount and vat within the report. I would like for each Invoice Number the description, amount and vat to show up.

Comment: put them in the **details** section of your report...

Comment: I have figured out the solution. The error was on my part. I had put the fields in the page header part rather than in the detail part of the report. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: You should consider posting that as a solution (i.e. answer your own question) in case others with the same problem come across this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to make sure that you are putting your data in the details section of your report.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the Table in the Details Section then i donot think that this situation will arise it will repeat the values as this is the property of the details section in IReport.